# Can't view webserver internal network Ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, server, webserver

I've installed an Ubuntu server running 14.04 that has Apache 2 and a small LXDE GUI.

I can view the website/server off of the network through a web browser, but the computers on the local network of the server can't.

Is there some configuration file or setting that I need to change in order to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using the internal or external IP address when trying to connect on the LAN?

Comment: All the computers server and workstations are on the same lan in the same subnet . There is no problem to ping the server.